# Wrapping the pure virtual function using Boost::Python

Tags: c++, boost-python, virtual-functions

I am now learning exposing c++ class to Python using `Boost::Python`, and I wrote the following code.

Compiling the code is all right. But when I import the code from Python side, it shows the following errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 1, in

```
import shape;
```

ImportError: /home/ruofan/Boost/Class/shape.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI7Polygon

How can I solve the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    Polygon (int a, int b) : width(a), height(b) {}
    virtual int area (void) =0;
    void printarea()
      { cout << this->area() << '\n'; }
    virtual ~Polygon(); 
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    Rectangle(int a,int b) : Polygon(a,b) {}
    int area()
      { return width*height; }
    virtual ~Rectangle();
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    Triangle(int a,int b) : Polygon(a,b) {}
    int area()
      { return width*height/2; }
    virtual ~Triangle();
};

struct BaseWrap : Polygon, wrapper<Polygon> {
  BaseWrap() : Polygon(0,0){}
  int area(){
        return this->get_override("area")();
  }
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(shape){
  class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Polygon")
    .def("area", pure_virtual(&Polygon::area));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that non-pure virtual functions are being declared but never defined.  This results in the library having undefined references to a class' typeinfo:

```
$ c++filt c++filt _ZTI7Polygon
typeinfo for Polygon
```

In this particular case, the destructors are never defined:

```cpp
class Polygon {
  ...
  public:
    ...
    virtual ~Polygon(); // Declared, but never defined.
};
```

To resolve this, define the `Polygyon` destructor:

```cpp
class Polygon {
  ...
  public:
    ...
    virtual ~Polygon() = default;
};
```

The same issue exists for `Rectangle` and `Triangle` types.  Although, one could omit declaring their destructors and allow the compiler to implicitly generate them.

---

The Boost.Python code for wrapping the pure-virtual function looks fine.  Here is a complete example based on the original code that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c3e72803eb3ccda) its usage:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Mockup abstract type.
class polygon
{
protected:
 int width, height;
public:
  polygon(int a, int b): width(a), height(b) {}
  virtual int area () = 0;
  virtual ~polygon() = default;
};

// Wrapper to allow calling Python overrides.
struct polygon_wrap
  : polygon, boost::python::wrapper<polygon>
{
  polygon_wrap(): polygon(0, 0) {}
  int area() { return this->get_override("area")(); }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose models.
  python::class_<polygon_wrap, boost::noncopyable>(
      "Polygon", python::init<>())
    .def("area", python::pure_virtual(&polygon::area))
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```
>>> import example
>>> class BadPolygon(example.Polygon):
...    pass
...
>>> class Square(example.Polygon):
...     def __init__(self, length):
...         example.Polygon.__init__(self)
...         self.length = length
...     def area(self):
...         return self.length**2
...
>>> try:
...     polygon = BadPolygon()
...     assert(isinstance(polygon, example.Polygon))
...     got_runtime_error = False
...     polygon.area()
... except RuntimeError:
...     got_runtime_error = True
... finally:
...     assert(got_runtime_error)
...
>>> polygon = Square(6)
>>> assert(isinstance(polygon, example.Polygon))
>>> assert(36 == polygon.area())
```